# Nested indenting issue

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, markdown-rendering

How to get correct indentation after entering a nested list?
I am writing a code review and I could not figure this out by googling. Here is an example of the three formatting styles I tried to use (but none of them works as I would like):

### Case 1

The task is to align the last line (see below) *"In the first line you use camelCase..."* with the last line above the numbered list.
In my first attempt, I added a new line (empty line) after the second numbered list item, and then indented by 4 spaces:

---

- **Variable name casing**: See [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) on *"Snake Case"*.
  In Perl, we use *"snake_case"* instead of *"camelCase"*, and be consistent. Example:

  1. Line 14: `my $testType`
  2. Line 18: `my $right_frame`

  In the first line you use camelCase, whereas in the second you use     snake_case.

---

As you can see, this gives the correct indentation but it introduces a blank line above the first numbered item.

### Case 2

In this case I do not add the blank line after the second numbered list item ( but still indent by 4 spaces ):

---

- **Variable name casing**: See [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) on *"Snake Case"*.
  In Perl, we use *"snake_case"* instead of *"camelCase"*, and be consistent. Example:

  1. Line 14: `my $testType`
  2. Line 18: `my $right_frame`
     In the first line you use camelCase, whereas in the second you use     snake_case.

---

In this case the line is considered as part of the last list item

### Case 3

In this case, I try to add two blank spaces (invisible) at the end of the second list item:

---

- **Variable name casing**: See [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) on *"Snake Case"*.
  In Perl, we use *"snake_case"* instead of *"camelCase"*, and be consistent. Example:

  1. Line 14: `my $testType`
  2. Line 18: `my $right_frame`
     In the first line you use camelCase, whereas in the second you use     snake_case.

---

In this case the line is considered part of the second item, and hence not correctly indented.

How to achieve the correct indentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your first try is correct and just suffers from the CSS applied—The first list item text is wrapped in a `<p>` tag which has a bottom margin but the nested list has no bottom margin and the following `<p>` has no top margin.

A simple (although not ideal) workaround, add a `<br>` to the beginning of paragraph following the nested list:

```
- **Variable name casing**: See [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) on *"Snake Case"*.
In Perl, we use *"snake_case"* instead of *"camelCase"*, and be consistent. Example:

    1. Line 14: `my $testType` 
    2. Line 18: `my $right_frame`

    <br>In the first line you use camelCase, whereas in the second you use     snake_case.
```

Which is rendered as this:

> - **Variable name casing**: See [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) on *"Snake Case"*.
>     In Perl, we use *"snake_case"* instead of *"camelCase"*, and be consistent. Example:
>
>   1. Line 14: `my $testType`
>   2. Line 18: `my $right_frame`
>
>   In the first line you use camelCase, whereas in the second you use     snake_case.

---

If you *really* don't want the extra space around the nested list I suppose you could forgo the list formatting and recreate it yourself with manual line breaks and extra spaces, like this:

```
- **Variable name casing**: See [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) on *"Snake Case"*.
In Perl, we use *"snake_case"* instead of *"camelCase"*, and be consistent. Example:
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1. Line 14: `my $testType`
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2. Line 18: `my $right_frame`
<br>In the first line you use camelCase, whereas in the second you use     snake_case.
```

Which is rendered as this:

> - **Variable name casing**: See [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) on *"Snake Case"*.
>     In Perl, we use *"snake_case"* instead of *"camelCase"*, and be consistent. Example:
>     
>      1. Line 14: `my $testType`
>     
>      2. Line 18: `my $right_frame`
>     
>   In the first line you use camelCase, whereas in the second you use     snake_case.

But then your nested list isn't really a list—it just looks a bit like one. I wouldn't really suggest doing this (I would correct this in an edit if I saw it), but it's a possibility.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to avoid the extra blank lines added around the numbered list? Like in Case 2 and Case 3?

Comment: I don't think so. The only reason you don't get them in the other cases is because there is no `<p>` tags inside the list, but as soon as you have more than one paragraph of text it adds the `<p>` tags around them

Comment: @HåkonHægland added a way to avoid the extra spacing around the list, I wouldn't advise actually using it though :)