# Why does line spacing depend on presence of subsequent lines in list items?

Tags: bug, design, code-formatting, list

Today I was editing a post on Ask Ubuntu, when I saw this odd behaviour:

1.
 [image]
2.
 [image]

In the first image, the "press enter..." line wasn't indented and hence not part of the list. The code block above it was close to the line above *it*.

In the second image, I indented the "press enter ..." line, and immediately the gap between the code block and the line above it increased.

Google Chrome 54.0.2840.90, Arch Linux

Comment: Similar issue [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286426/307988), only with nested lists rather than code. It's just a consequence of the different HTML that is generated and the margins applied to elements within lists.