# Markdown: Fix for excessive vertical spacing? Uh, no, that's a feature already requested!

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

How can I fix the excessive vertical spacing between "like:" and "cat.." below? Notice there is no empty line in the markdown, but an abyss in the rendering of the HTML.

Update: this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286428/184379) gives a rather ugly workaround (it uses numbering by hand) to a similar issue. I can't find how to transpose that workaround to bullets, not make the long line starting with cat indent properly.

Update 2: this turns out to be a CSS bug-or-very-poor-choice, and a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287967/307988) as pointed in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300824/184379#comment977988_300824).

---

### Example

1. **Mammals**

   like:

   - cat multidisciplinary study including sedimentologic, stratigraphic, isotopic, and palynological aspects in order to reconstruct the paleoenvironment and to evaluate biochronologic and paleogeographic implications.
   - cow
   - dog

   New faunal and stratigraphic evidence documents the validity of the North American Clarkforkian.
2. **Smurf**

---

That is produced by this markdown:

```
___
Example
-
1. **Mammals**

 like:
- cat multidisciplinary study including sedimentologic, stratigraphic, isotopic, and palynological aspects in order to reconstruct the paleoenvironment and to evaluate biochronologic and paleogeographic implications.
- cow
- dog

 New faunal and stratigraphic evidence documents the validity of the North American Clarkforkian.

2. **Smurf**
```

and translates into this HTML

```
<hr>

<h2>Example</h2>

<ol>
<li><p><strong>Mammals</strong></p>

<p>like:</p>

<ul><li>cat multidisciplinary study including sedimentologic, stratigraphic, isotopic, and palynological aspects in order to reconstruct the paleoenvironment and to evaluate biochronologic and paleogeographic implications.</li>
<li>cow</li>
<li>dog</li></ul>

<p>New faunal and stratigraphic evidence documents the validity of the North American Clarkforkian.</p></li>
<li><p><strong>Smurf</strong></p></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: See also [Better nested list styling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287967/307988)